# Download zip file without extraction from direct link

Tags: python, download, zip

i'm trying to make a script that downloads files from direct links (such as this one : "http://beatsaver.com/api/download/key/f55c" ) with a Python script.
I've tried various code from here or / other website to either end up with a corrupted zip file or a

> "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file".

I tried with this : (zip corrupted)

```
url = "http://beatsaver.com/api/download/key/f55c"
resp = requests.get(url)
zname = os.path.join('BeatSong', "song_test.zip")
zfile = open(zname, 'wb')
zfile.write(resp.content)
zfile.close()
```

or 3 or 4 variation of this : ( raise : "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file")

```
url = "http://beatsaver.com/api/download/key/f55c"
resp = requests.get(url)
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
zip.extractall("/BeatSong")
```

The link download the zip automatically when loaded
Any ways of retrieving the zip file as it would be like when I download it from the browser?

Comment: How does the file downloaded this way differ from the file downloaded by browser?

Comment: The point is to automate the downloading of a a few hundred of them, instead of clicking on them one by one

Comment: Ow i misunderstood your question. I just  can't open the zip downloaded with the script it says something along the line of "damaged archive or unrecognized format" (computer not in english)
The browser zip file is just fine

Comment: I mean, do the files differ in size? And what differences do you see when you look at the bytes? Might give some insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: Ah yeah indeed ! Script file weight around 4KB while the browser one is around 8MB

Comment: Ok, that's of course very wrong. Now open that 4KB file in a text editor and read.

Comment: Cloudflare restricted ? Does that mean that autodownload bots are not allowed then ? Sorry, i'm still rather new to all of this

Comment: That seems to be the intention, yes.

Comment: Alright so the script is fine but can do it this way on this website, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the url is returning a 403 forbidden error when trying to get it with python.  The site is refusing to send you the file because it knows you are a bot.  I was able to get past this by setting the user-agent.

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://beatsaver.com/api/download/key/f55c"

#add headers so you don't get a 403 error
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'song.zip', )
```

Comment: Ow awesome ! This user agent is the one used by Chrome right? (i've just read a quick tutorial on it rn) 
Thank for your time !

Comment: Yes, I just copied the user-agent from the browser I was using.  There are tools out there like https://pypi.org/project/random-user-agent/ that will provide a random user agent.  Also make sure you space out your downloads because we know beatsaver is blocking bots and you don't give them another way to identify your app as a bot.